# Normalization of potential barrier solution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, scattering, normalization

I don't understand a point in the solution attached to this barrier potential problem. Below equation 4.209, they say

> *Assume first that the wave function on the right side of the barrier in the region $x> a/2 $ is $ \psi(x)=e^{ikx}$.*

Why assume first that the coefficient is 1? I understand the main idea of the solution that is to solve a matrix equation for two piece-wise constant potential (barrier). Do you suggest a better or clearer solution?

[image: statement of problem]

[image: solution]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have the freedom to define the wavefunctions, such that one of the leading coefficients is one. Suppose you didn't do this, and instead defined:

$$ \psi(x') = C_1e^{ikx'}, x' > \frac{a}{2}$$
$$ \psi(x') = C_2 e^{ikx'} + C_3 e^{-ikx'}, x' < \frac{a}{2}$$

Then, you could divide through by $C_1$ to give:

$$ \psi(x') = e^{ikx'}, x' > \frac{a}{2}$$
$$ \psi(x') = \frac{C_2}{C_1} e^{ikx'} + \frac{C_3}{C_1} e^{-ikx'} = A e^{ikx'} + B e^{-ikx'}, x' < \frac{a}{2}$$

Here, $A = \frac{C_2}{C_1}$ and $B =\frac{C_3}{C_1}$.

You do this when you match the continuity of the wavefunction and its derivative. This is the motivation for why they do this.

Comment: thanks, @grover . But if you set the coefficient equal to 1 ,  then if you see in the problem statement they recommend to use a solution where the coefficient in the right side of the well is t . But we set it 1 and then try to calculate it ?? i am a bit confused.

Comment: @Mati Using what Grover said you can find your answer. $t$ was set to $1$ therefore $A_1\rightarrow A=A_1/t$ and $B_1\rightarrow B=B_1/t$. Once you solved for this new constant your have to bring back everithing to the form of eq.(4.78) in order to find the transmission and refelection paramenter ($t$ and $r$). This is exactly what is done in eqs.(4.213-214). The misleading bit can be that at the beginning he is calling $A_r$ and $B_r$ the constants for the transmitted particle.